# skip option not working in for loop, batch script

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, token, operator-precedence

I have the following code:

```
for /F "tokens=3 skip=2 usebackq" %%A in (`"REG QUERY !KEY_NAME! /v VALUE_NAME!"`) do (
    set SafeSignVersionValue=%%A
    @echo SafeSign Version = !SafeSignVersionValue! >> %USERNAME%.txt
)
```

It is part of a script that is executed at logon of every user in our domain
(it resides in the SysVol folder). The result of the reg query is of 3 lines
(1st line is blank). I'm interested in the 3rd token of the last line (thus 
tokens=3 and skip=2).

When i run this script 'locally' (in my computer) from the console window
it works ok: i get the data i'm looking for.

If the script is run from SYSVOL it does not work correctly. It seems not to
skip the first 2 lines (skip=2 not working?) because I get 2 lines in output

SafeSign Version = xxxx         (gets the 3rd token from the 1st line)
  SafeSign Version = yyyy         (gets the 3rd token from the 2nd line)

Why is that? Does it have to do with the order of tokens, skip? It's the
only thing I can think of, but if it is, why it matters when running as part
of logon (SYSVOL), but it does not if ran locally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `VALUE_NAME!` should be `!VALUE_NAME!`.

Comment: made a mistake when pasting/editing the code. the !  is in there.

Comment: Actually I don't get an empty line as the first line in the output of `reg query`; I only get two lines: the first one containing the queried key, followed by an empty line... so I can't reproduce your issue...

Comment: i get 4 lines on screen (CMD console): 1st and 4th empty, 2nd and 3rd with info. if i redirect output to txt file and open it in editor i only get 2 lines with info and a 3rd line empty (a CR i believe). would have to check with hex editor

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the 3rd value of the LAST line. You can do it without SKIP.
The last line will be the Last evaluated.

Try like this :

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('REG QUERY !KEY_NAME! /v !VALUE_NAME!') do set "SafeSignVersionValue=%%A"

@echo SafeSign Version = !SafeSignVersionValue! >> %USERNAME%.txt
```

Comment: tried that. it does not work. i get two lines evaluated. HOWEVER it does work with a similar reg query. why is that? i do not know :(